# ASP.NET + PHP in Azure simultaneously

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

Can you have both PHP and ASP.NET/C# code running in the same Microsoft Azure WebApp?

I have a site that uses PHP/WordPress on a WebApp and I'd like to use that same WebApp to host an ASP.NET/c# application under a specific folder.

Something along the lines of:
 - www.sample-PHP-wordpress-site.com
and
 - www.sample-PHP-wordpress-site.com/some-ASP.NET-site-hosted-here

Comment: nope. closest you can get is url redirect

Answer (score 0):

As I know, it is supported. I have do a simple test, here is my steps.

1) Enable PHP in Azure portal. Refer to [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/) for more information about how to enable php.

2) Write a php file with the content 'this is php site', then use FTP upload to wwwroot folder.

3) Create virtual directory in Azure portal, then publish web site to Azure Web app. See more detailed steps [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/).

After above steps, you will see below screenshot. 
[image]
And It is easily to redirect to asp site via below code:

```html
<?php 
header("Location: aspsite/Default.aspx"); 
?>
```